# Query was empty error | Trying to get a specific Mysql Value

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks in advance for any help you could bring, I'm really noob on all coding stuffs but this is the situation:

I have a wordpress website focused on Travel Agency Tours and hotels, and I'm working on an extranet system, the idea is that hotel managers will be able to change the price of their rooms, but this extranet works totally apart of wordpress, its a php script, with a different mysql database, so, what I would like to do is that when the price is changed in the extranet, then in wordpress this is going to be also changed in real time, so I'm trying in this way:

I'm planning to insert a php snippet on wordpress editor with a mysql code to get the price from the other database for each hotel and room, so, I'm going to do this for every hotel manually, the problem becomes from the code im trying to use to get that value:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'test_user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbname = 'test_db';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `room_price`, FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'");


$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Room Price :{$row['room_price']}  <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

So the result I get in my test.php file with this code is:

> "Could not get data: Query was empty"

I'm not sure why is this error, and why is not printing the value I want.

PostData: I really appologize for my english since is not my language, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: It was not empty, it was with error. Check `mysql_error`

Comment: @user55125,I have posted answer of your question,Please check it now ! It will resolve your issue. Let me know if you still have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and try connection like this

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
```

You need to remove coma from your query after room price

```
//You are running the query twice so use this query 

$sql = "SELECT `room_price` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'";
```

and learn `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` are deprciated and soon going be drop

Comment: removing the coma and changing the way i was connecting worked, Thanks a lot to everyone helping.

Comment: I did as you said, and turned the code to mysqli, but now im trying to do something different with the code right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756761/conditional-mysqli-date-range-check-to-print-a-price-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

For select database use `mysql_select_db()` . you can't pass dbname as an args in `mysql_connect()`

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);
```

Also if you are learner then learn **mysqli** or **PDO**

Note :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated

you are calling query run two times so change below lines

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `room_price`, FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'");
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

to

```
$retval = mysql_query("SELECT `room_price` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'");
```

Comment: Hi, i did as you suggest, but nothing changes, by the way you are right i should learn mysqli or PDO, and i will, or at least im trying, really appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: Did it and it worked, also the coma after room_price, was a mistake from me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have send the query two times...

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT `room_price`, FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks... If i do that i get this error instead: Could not get data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'' at line 1

Comment: there is a comma between the output row and the FROM part of the statement

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dbhost      = 'localhost';
$dbuser      = 'test_user';
$dbpass      = 'pass';
$dbname      = 'test_db';
$conn        = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use test_db : ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT `room_price` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Room Price :{$row['room_price']}  <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: mysql_selectdb($dbname); ?

Comment: Select database $dbname = 'test_db';

Comment: tried ?function is correct? try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: @RakeshSharma,There was typo mistake,Corrected ! Thanks for notified.