# Conditional mysqli date range check to print a price in sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, conditional-statements

This time I'm trying to make some php code to work with mysqli in order to check if today date is between a range of dates in a Mysql table, if the condition is true I need to print a price from a table otherwise it shuould print a different price from another table. so I already have all sql connections set in another php file, the problem is that when I try the code, it just shows nothing, a blank page only. This is the code im using:

```
<?php
$currentdate = date("Y/m/d");                               
//basic include files
require_once('/home/user/public_html/folder/db.php');

$seasonalpricedate = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `seasonal_price` FROM `hotel_seasonal_price` WHERE room_type_id = '1' AND $currentdate >= 'seasonal_from' AND $currentdate <= 'seasonal_to';");
$result = ($seasonalpricedate) or die(mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    $standardprice = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `room_price` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'");
    if(! $standardprice ){
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    while($standard = mysqli_fetch_array($standardprice, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo "$ {$standard['room_price']} ";
    }
} else {
    if(! $seasonalpricedate ){
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());

        while($standard2 = mysqli_fetch_array($seasonalpricedate, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo "$ {$standard2['seasonal_price']} ";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I already tried both codes with standardprice and seasonalprice working without a conditional, but when I try to do it like this, it does not show anything.

PostData: Im still trying to learn english, so please appologize me if I fail some words, thanks in Advance.

UPDATE: Ok so in this way it works if there is no values true its ok, it shows the standardprice, but if match the date, dont show anything, here is the code changed:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");                               
//basic include files
require_once('/home/trankilo/public_html/book/db.php');

$seasonalpricedate = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `seasonal_price` FROM `hotel_seasonal_price` WHERE room_type_id = '1' AND '$currentdate' >= seasonal_from AND '$currentdate' <= seasonal_to");
$result = ($seasonalpricedate) or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
$seasonalprice = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `seasonal_price` FROM `hotel_seasonal_price` WHERE room_type_id = '1'");
if(! $seasonalprice )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
while($standard2 = mysqli_fetch_array($seasonalprice, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "$ {$standard2['seasonal_price']} ";
}
}

} else {
$standardprice = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `room_price` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'");
if(! $standardprice )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
while($standard = mysqli_fetch_array($standardprice, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "$ {$standard['room_price']} ";
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

So close to make it work, thanks to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Because you are also updated your  OP, now i found what causes the problem. Ther proble were when you says: `die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());` And after that you want to try a `while` loop. while won't executed, because you terminated the script with a `die();` Move the `while` to the `else` case of your `if` condition. See my comments.

Use this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

//Also display your errors.
display_errors(true);

$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
//basic include files
require_once('/home/trankilo/public_html/book/db.php');

//Put your query into a variable, so you can dump / print it.
$sql = "SELECT `seasonal_price`"
    . " FROM `hotel_seasonal_price`"
    . " WHERE room_type_id = '1'"
    . " AND '" . $currentdate . "' >= seasonal_from"
    . " AND '" . $currentdate . "' <= 'seasonal_to'";
echo $sql;
//Try to run it in the sql directly. Is it gives back you any result?
//Do not need to 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    //Check if we have result by echoing some dummy text
    echo "Yes, we have result!";

    $sql = "SELECT `seasonal_price` FROM `hotel_seasonal_price` WHERE room_type_id = '1'";
    //Do the same as the previous query. Does it gives you back anything?
    $seasonalprice = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (!$seasonalprice) {
        //I do not really get what happens here. If you have no seasonalprice, 
        //then you can not fetch_array on that!
        //Move this whole section.... You've say die, and after that do a while?
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
    } else {
        while ($standard2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seasonalprice)) {
            echo "$ " . $standard2['seasonal_price'] . " ";
        }
    }
} else {
    //Same as previous
    $sql = "SELECT `room_price` FROM `hotel_room_price` WHERE price_id = '1'";
    $standardprice = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (!$standardprice) {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
        //same here, move the while to the else...
    } else {
        while ($standard = mysqli_fetch_array($standardprice, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "$ {$standard['room_price']} ";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped, and worked like a charm, i edited your answer with a second update, with only a few changes, to make it, really appreciate your help!. I still have to learn a lot.

Comment: I removed your edit, because there was syntax error. Anyway, you are welcome!